# "Subquery returns more than 1 row" Error

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I read many posts but i can't understand the error and my query that are to be written.

i want that poster_id that have like more than 1000 like

```
SELECT * FROM `posters` 
WHERE title LIKE '%it%'
AND id = (
    SELECT poster_id FROM `poster_likes`
    WHERE action=1
    GROUP BY poster_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 100
  )
```

The sub-query return more than one row.

Can any one please write this query for me. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean to be using `IN()` instead of `=`:

```
SELECT * FROM `posters` 
WHERE title LIKE '%it%'
AND id IN (
    SELECT poster_id FROM `poster_likes`
    WHERE action=1
    GROUP BY poster_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 100
  )
```

Comment: Also probably wants `COUNT(*) > 1000`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using `where id =(subquery)`  but your subquery returns more than one value so:

change

```
where id =(subquery)
```

To

```
where id  in (subquery)
```

Comment: MySQL does not have `TOP`

Comment: This can only return top one poster_id ... but i want all

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery returns more than one rows. You conditions is `id = (more than one thing)` and sql can't resove that. You can use `in` clause

```
SELECT * FROM `posters` 
WHERE title LIKE '%it%'
AND id IN ( -- = changed to IN
    SELECT poster_id FROM `poster_likes`
    WHERE action=1
    GROUP BY poster_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 100
  )
```

or select only the first result.